# Android push notifications - should my service extend GCMBaseIntentService or IntentService

Tags: android

The basic architecture of the push functionality that I am trying to create is

1) I would get the phone id and store it in my db

2) Only when something happened on the server I would try to create a push message

So I do not need the part where the app tries to call the server to send it the message. I am wondering what should I extend in the Service class and what methods in it do I need to implement.

Also, am I able to get the device id and send that info to my server without using the server?

I am using Google cloud messaging.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Lets go through this 1 point at a time.  What do you mean by the phone id?

Comment: @Kevin Bradshaw I meant the unique id of the phone to which I would send the push notification. It is the id that is needed to make the push notification.  Does that help make it more clear? :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to get the registration ID for you phone you will need to do the following in an activity:

```
     import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;
    private final static String SENDER_ID = "0001234567" // API Key, see comments;

    public class myActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {

            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
            regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
 if (regId.equals("")) 
        {
             GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
             Log.i(TAG,"registered a new ID");
        } 
        else 
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"Already Registered");
        }
```

your google reg will be contained in regId

You will need this in your Manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="my.namespace" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

where my.namespace will equal whatever your package name is

Comment: thanks, but on the first time opening the app, will that if/else go to the if block or the else block? I am just trying to figure out when to send the remote call.

Comment: Edited the code to show how to handle first time registration

Comment: Your sender ID is obtained by following the instructions here http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#access-key

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html).. it uses the new GooglecloudMessaging API. And yes, you should extend **IntentService** cause the other ones deprecated now.